# How to store the value of stdin into an array in C?

Tags: c, stdin

I'm facing a problem to store a file coming from the standard input into a buffer.

Here is my code :

```
//Go to the end of stdin and calculate the number of elements
int num;
fseek (stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
num = ftell (stdin); 

//If there is a file in the standard input
if(num > 0) {

    int resRead;

    //Read the file and store it into buffer
    if((resRead = read(STDIN_FILENO,buffer,num))){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not store the input into buffer\n");
    }

    //Display the buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
    printf("%c\n",buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

When i launch my code : ./interpreter < file.txt, i don't get the content of the buffer.

I've to precise that my file has content and when i check the value of num it correspond exactly to the number of char in the file.

Any ideas ? :)

Thank you !!

Comment: why on earth are you doing `fseek()` and `ftell()` on stdin? I can't imagine that would do what you'd expect.

Comment: @ChrisTurner: If stdin is redirected from a file (as seems to be the case), that can work...

Comment: @MaxUt: There are two main problems: (1) You're mixing C library functions (`fseek`, `ftell` etc) with kernel functions (`read` etc), which may cause problems.. (2) You're seeking to the end of the file, and then trying to read from it - so you get no data, because there's none left! You probably want to seek back to the start. (In addition to that, as others have pointed out, if you need to seek in the input it's usually better to take a filename on the command line and use `open()` or `fopen()` - but if you know stdin will `always` be redirected from a file, yours *should* work).

Comment: @psmears great thank you. Do you have any idea how to make sure that there is a file redirected to stdin beside checking with fseek()?

Answer (score 0):

Operating system level streaming or indirection of a file to a binary does not work in this scenario unless you have file reading code from standard input in your program.

Better option is keep the file in directory and pass the file location as parameter to your program. And use [fopen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

`stdin` is a stream, which means that it doesn't have an "end" that you can seek to.  There's no way to know if it received a redirected file or if it's reading user input from the console.

You need to dynamically allocate space for your buffer using `malloc` and read in up to as many bytes as you can fit.  If there's still more data, use `realloc` to expand the buffer (a good strategy is to double the size each time) and read more.

If you know you'll always be reading from a file, you should change the program to take the file name from the command line and use `fopen` to open the file.

Comment: Actually `stdin` *will* have an end that can be `seek()`ed to if the process has its input redirected from a file, as is happening in this question.